# How to get fulfillment for both sets of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making a chatbot on Dialogflow that can do various things (I've basically followed a few tutorials that Dialogflow has put out, re-formatted the code slightly and made some adjustments to it for my own).

The code is long, so I'll put the link to a Github below. Also, I'm using the inline editor on dialogflow

The problem/ I'm not really sure what to do is I have a user login section (lines 33 to 51) where a user can login to their google account via voice.

In the tutorials, in the fulfillment line they have (I'm almost certain this is the reason it isn't working):

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

But the problem , to fulfill my other functions I need to have:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 ..... Functions under }
```

I had attempted to write variations thinking that this might work:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((app, request, response)

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app(request, response) 
// Syntax error
```

How could I get the two halves of the code working together? Is it possible to do this or do I have to re-format this again, or do I just have to do something a little different with the fulfillment line?

Thanks for the help!

code [here](https://github.com/lando22/dialogflowchatbot/blob/master/dialogbot)

**Note:** In the code on Github, I did not change the fulfillment line, I just left it in the form that my other functions would work. ***The code has been tested for the login and WORKS, it does NOT WORK with the other functions I have written.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the two libraries have different ways of setting up the listener that handles the request/response objects and setting up the intent handler registration. You can't mix the two (as you've discovered). You need to pick one and convert the functions registered the other way.

To save myself a lot of typing, I'm going to refer to the actions-on-google library as a-o-g and the dialogflow-fulfillment library as d-f.

**Using the actions-on-google library**

You would initialize the listener with something like:

```
const app = dialogflow({
  // REPLACE THE PLACEHOLDER WITH THE CLIENT_ID OF YOUR ACTIONS PROJECT
  clientId: '<CLIENT ID>',
});

// Intent handler declarations go here

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Converting the dialogflow-fulfillment-style handlers is relatively straightforward. The a-o-g `conv` object is fairly similar to the d-f `agent` object. Both, for example, have an `add()` method that behave the same way when dealing with Actions.

The `conv` object also has a `parameters` property, although using the second argument in the function call is preferred, it contains the same things. Similarly, it has an `arguments` property which contains the same thing as the third argument passed to the handler.

It is also worth noting that `app.intent()` doesn't have to have its function as an arrow function or even specified inline like that. You can write the function separately and just pass it as a parameter.

So your `makeAppointment()` function might be re-written and registered as something like

```
  function makeAppointment (conv) {
    // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
    const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(conv.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
    const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
    const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
      'en-US',
      { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
    );

    // Check the availibility of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
    return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
      conv.add(`Okay, I have you booked for ${appointmentTimeString}!`);
    }).catch(() => {
      conv.add(`I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.`);
    });
  }
  app.intent( 'Make Appointment', makeAppointment );
```

**Using the dialogflow-fulfillment library**

You already have the listener and handler setup this way

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  // Declare your functions here

  let intentMap = new Map();
  // Map intent name to functions here
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

so the question is how to turn the handlers, which appear to have a-o-g specific information in the function arguments, into d-f compatible handlers.

The d-f `agent` object has a way to get the (nearly) equivalent `conv` object. Unsurprisingly, it is `agent.getConv()`. Really. You can then use the `parameters` and `arguments` properties as noted above to get the equivalent of the second and third function arguments. You'll use `agent.add()` to add a message (you can use `conv` as well, but its a little more complicated).

It might look something like this for the "Get Signin" handler:

```
function getSignin (agent){
  let conv = agent.getConv();
  let params = conv.parameters;
  let signin = conv.arguments;
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
    agent.ask(`Welcome back ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`);
  } else {
    agent.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`);
  }
}
```

and then make sure you register the handler in the appropriate place

```
intentMap.set('Get Signin', getSignin);
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're mixing 2 different versions of the Actions on Google library. It's recommended you stick with V2, which means changing the Intent-map to intent handlers instead.

```
// Intent that starts the account linking flow.
app.intent('Start Signin', conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});

// Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event.
app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
    if (signin.status === 'OK') {
        const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
        conv.ask(`Welcome back ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`);
  } else {
      conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`);
  }
});

app.intent('Make Appointment', (conv) => {
    /* some code here */
});

app.intent('ReadFromFirestore', (conv) => {
    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent'
    const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');

    // Get the value of 'entry' in the document and send it to the user
    return dialogflowAgentDoc.get().then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          conv.tell('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          conv.ask(doc.data().entry);
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        conv.ask('Error reading entry from the Firestore database. Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
    });
});

app.intent('WriteToFirestore', (conv) => {
    /* some code here */
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

(methods omitted)

The "app" (dialogflow) object already wraps the request and response arguments, so there isn't anything you should do to interfere with those.

If you want separate endpoints, outside of dialogflow, to do stuff: you can add additional functions like so:

```
exports.someOtherFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    /* do something with the request and response here */
});
```

These won't directly have much to do with Dialogflow, however.